# Using top level fetch in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am a bit confused. The idea is to write write ES2022 in order to use top level `await` and `fetch`, to use in NodeJS only.

Following the compiler advice:

```
src/index.ts:48:3 - error TS1378: Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.
```

I have set the `module` to es2022, and the target to es2020 (which is enough in my case.)

I want the target to be ES2020 so that older versions of node would run the code.

According to TS there shouldn't e a problem with this (see config at the bottom)

Yet once compiled I get the error that

```
await fetch(...)

ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
```

This is my tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "lib-esm",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "es2022",
    "target": "es2020"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
}
```

Why would it be so ? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Silly error, I just had to change nvm to node version 19 (that supports fetch):

```
nvm use 19
```